# Why parenthesis() are not used for some functions like @@IDENTITY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have seen many functions, on every function I see they have parenthesis`()` on its end like,

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TableName');
```

But why some function's do not use `with parenthesis()` like function

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

Answer (score 2):

@@xxxxx are system functions without parameters which should be treated as read-only variables

Comment: but without parameters fuction uses the () sysmbol

Comment: yes, there are many functions with parenthesis and without parameters, like sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn().  They just decided to do it in different ways for many functions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that these *used* to be referred to as "server variables" and so had a "variable-like" syntax rather than a function syntax. They have since been re-defined as functions, but maintain the older syntax for backwards-compatibility.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any online resources presently to back-up this claim, and I think the "server variables" definition had been retired by the 2000 release of the product.

---

If we take the example of `@@ROWCOUNT`. In SQL Server 2000 BOL, it's described as:

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.
>
> ...
>
> This *variable* is set...

(My *emphasis*).

Compare that with the [current documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx), which refers to it having its value set but now avoids referring to it as a variable (or a function). And, of course, it's modern, enhanced, doesn't have to support backwards compatibility sibling [`ROWCOUNT_BIG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181406.aspx) which has normal function syntax. And is explicitly referred to as a function.

---

I do not believe that Microsoft have introduced any *new* functions using the `@@` variable syntax since before 2000 was released.